# HTML in APEX not giving correct base URL with ahref

Tags: apex, email-template, html

```
       Account acc = [Select Id,Name,Owner.Name FROM Account WHERE Id =: accId];
       String HtmlBody='Attention Data Analyst,<br><br>';
       HtmlBody+='Please verify the Account: ' + '</b> + acc.Name+ </b> <br><br>';

       HtmlBody+='The link to the Account is : <a href="'+System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+acc.Id+'">Click Here</a> <br><br>';
       HtmlBody+='For questions about the Account contact the Account Owner ' +acc.Owner.name+' <br><br>';
       HtmlBody+='For Salesforce questions contact salesforcesupport@XXXX.com  <br>';
```

**I have two questions**

1. How to display the value of 'acc.name' in bold ?

   ```
   HtmlBody+='Verify the Account: ' + acc.Name+ '<br><br>';
   ```
2. link is different in execute anonymous and the email that i get. Why ?

   **Execute Anonymous :**
     system.debug('--'+System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm());

   // URL is correctly displayed

   ```
    https://xxx--Dev2.cs62.my.salesforce.com
   ```

   **Apex:**

   // URL is

   ```
   https://dev2-xxx.cs62.force.com/'<recordid>'
   ```

Can some one please suggest what changes I need to make to get the correct URL?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your HTML is wrong. `</b> + acc.Name+ </b>`: you have two closing tags, and no opening `<b>` tag.
2. Both domain names are correct. Salesforce URLs may take a variety of forms based on the context; for example, my developer edition goes by `<my domain>-dev-ed.na82.force.com` when it is displaying a Classic application, and `<my domain>-dev-ed.lightning.force.com` when in Lightning.

Comment: When i click on the hyperlink it does'nt navigate to the record. It gives an error ' Page Not Found: /0015C00000SmqusQAB '

Comment: Does that ID exist? Is there a spurious character before or after it?

Comment: Yes, that Id exists. Doesn't seem like there is a spurious character around it. But I will recheck.  HtmlBody+='The link to the Account is : <a href="'+System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+acc.Id+'">Click Here</a> <br><br>';

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[Per Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm), another option is that you can get the domain URL to appropriately link records in this type of situation and it should work in both contexts (Lightning and Classic).

```
HtmlBody+='The link to the Account is : <a href="'+System.getOrgDomainURL()+'/'+acc.Id'">Click Here</a> <br><br>';System.getOrgDomainURL()
```

Comment: Thanks Kris! I already deployed with a work around. 
Created a custom setting and saved OrgDomainURL as a field value (see this thread..)
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290500/test-class-get-custom-setting-value-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment435698_290500